# Mysql stuck with order by desc and limit

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
"id"    "UserName"  "score"
"1"     "User 1"    "2"
"2"     "User 2"    "5"
"3"     "User 3"    "3"
"4"     "User 4"    "7"
"5"     "User 5"    "1"
```

and run an sql like this:

```
select userName from stack where id >= 0 order by score DESC LIMIT 3
```

That gives me the result

```
"userName"
"User 4"
"User 2"
"User 3"
```

Which means its arranged like this this;

```
"id"    "UserName"  "score"
"4"     "User 4"    "7"
"2"     "User 2"    "5"
"3"     "User 3"    "3"
"1"     "User 1"    "2"
"5"     "User 5"    "1"
```

How can I start at `id 1` and get results as below. Because no matter what I do, I keep getting incorrect results:

**Expected results:**

```
select userName from stack where id >= 1 order by score DESC LIMIT 3

"1" "User 1"    "2" /*These are my expected results and not what the above query outputs*/
"5" "User 5"    "1"
```

This whole thing comes from a pagination system where we use to display users based on their scores.

Comment: Why start with User 1 (id 1) if he/she doesn't have the highest score (order by score desc)? If you want User 1's score first all the time, then the next 3 highest, then you need to run 2 SELECTs and use UNION. Good luck.

Comment: Are you looking to get the next three? In which case, you want `SELECT userName FROM stack ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3,3`

Comment: @Grim... The first set is User 4, 2, 3. So the next set will start at 1, so  it'll be User 1 and 5. 3 results per page. 4,2,3 are the first, 1 and 5 will be on page 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an offset in the LIMIT:

```
select userName from stack where id >= 1 order by score DESC LIMIT 3,3
```

For your pagination you have to increase your offset for every page.

Comment: That `>=1` is fairly superfluous, I'd guess.

Comment: So what would have to keep changing here? The second number after the `,`

Comment: No, the first number. `LIMIT [offset],[returned rows]`

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be woking very well.